# Weird name in iMessage when I copy messages

Tags: messages

I just copied a text I got in messages and for some reason it shows my name as `Pumpkin Squealer De Luz Do You See`:

`555-555-5555
    Sorry Jake. Will be back to you later today with someone to come out.
Pumpkin Squealer De Luz Do You See:
    Ok sounds good!`

How in the world is this happening? Is there somewhere that your username gets set? Makes no sense

Comment: This has got to be one of the funniest questions I have seen :) but I may have a solution

Comment: My son told Siri to call me something haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this – Both which are caused by a friends most likely playing a prank on you – : Your name is incorrect on your contact, or your nickname is incorrect on your contact. I will be assuming your on an iPhone and not a Mac. If I have assumed incorrectly just comment and I'll change my answer although the steps are basically identical.

### **Change Your Name**

1. Open Contacts and select the first contact labeled with "My Card"
   [image]
2. Select Edit in the upper right hand corner
   [image]
3. Delete the name listed in `First Name` and `Last Name` (`Pumpkin Squealer De Luz Do You See`) and replace it with your real name

[image]

### **Change Your Nickname** (If available)

**Method 1:**

1. Steps 1 & 2 from "Change Your Name"
2. Change the Nickname (Most likely 3rd option) or remove it completely

[image]

**Method 2: (How your friend probably did it)**

1. Ask Siri "Call Me [Insert Nickname Here]"

This will change your nickname.

### **Prevent this in the Future**

I know your probably asking *Wait...? I have a password on my phone how did my friend get in?*. Great question! Although you have a password, Siri, by default, is enabled on the lock screen giving the lots of power including changing your nickname, sending texts, reading emails (from third party apps), etc. Assuming that this was the way they did it you can turn off Siri from lock screen by going to Settings>Touch ID & PasscodeSiri.

Comment: This is on my computer. I think I have come up with a possible reason this happened. My son will press the siri button on my macbook pro and yell nonsense so I'm thinking this is the cause =D

Comment: Ok. I can edit if you would like. But it’s basically same instructions just go to contacts on your Mac and edit your contact. Or just ask Siri “Call me <name>”

Comment: Yep, makes sense.